# Display user selected color as a rectangle and string WPF C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm writing a WPF application where the user may selected a color from a windows form color dialog and the selected color is displayed in a listbox. The selected color will display as a listbox item with a rectangle that is the selected color and a string of the name of the selected Color. However I am unable to have the rectangle and color name display. When I run the program with just the rectangle being added to the listbox it displays the rectangle. However when I add the color name it displays the rectangle as a string.

C#

```
private void addNewItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ColorDialog cd = new ColorDialog();
        if (cd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var itemsCount = lstControl.Items.Count;
            var colorName = cd.Color;
            //Create rectangle object
            System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle myRect = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
            myRect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(colorName.A, colorName.R, colorName.G, colorName.B));
            myRect.Height = 10;
            myRect.Width = 10;

            var newItem = new ListBoxItem
            {

                Content = myRect + colorName.ToString()

            };
            lstControl.Items.Add(newItem);
        }
    }
```

WPF

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstControl"
             Width="300" Height="85" Margin="10 10 20 4">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,3,0,0">
                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,0,0"/>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                    <Rectangle Width="30" Fill="{Binding SampleBrush}"/>
                    <TextBlock Width="130" Text="{Binding ColorName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing in code behind,  I created a collection of newly created class `ColorData` by using this, we will be fully able to utilize the item template.

Step 1:- `ColorData` class creation

```
public class ColorData
{
    public ColorData(Brush color, String colorName)
    {
        ColorBrush = color;
        ColorText = colorName;
    }
    public Brush ColorBrush { get; set; }
    public string ColorText { get; set; }
}
```

Step 2:- Create a Observable Collection of the `ColorData` Class and initiate it inside constructor and to support binding, I have given **this.DataContext = this;**

```
public ObservableCollection<ColorData> ColorCollection { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    ColorCollection = new ObservableCollection<ColorData>();
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Step 3:- Add the ColorBrush and Color Name inside the Collection.

```
private void addNewItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ColorDialog cd = new ColorDialog();
    if (cd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var itemsCount = lstControl.Items.Count;
        var colorName = cd.Color;
        //Create rectangle object
        System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle myRect = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
        myRect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(colorName.A, colorName.R, colorName.G, colorName.B));

        ColorCollection.Add(new ColorData(new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(colorName.A, colorName.R, colorName.G, colorName.B)), colorName.Name ));
    }
}
```

Step 4:- Changes XAML (Changed only the `PropertyName` in Binding)
Name your Window/ UserControl. To support ElementBinding. In this case, I have used `Window1`

Instead of SampleBrush & ColorName Property in Binding, used the ColorBrush & ColorText and 
then binded the Property.
`ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window1,Path=DataContext.ColorCollection}`

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstControl" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window1,Path=DataContext.ColorCollection}"
             Width="300" Height="85" Margin="10 10 20 4">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,3,0,0">
                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,0,0"/>
                            </Style>
                        </StackPanel.Resources>
                        <Rectangle Width="30" Fill="{Binding ColorBrush}"/>
                        <TextBlock Width="130" Text="{Binding ColorText}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

**Alternate**
If you do not want to go by above method of binding and follow the same method, then I have tweaked your code by adding Grid layout consisting of rectangle and Textblock as Children of Grid Layout.

```
 private void addNewItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ColorDialog cd = new ColorDialog();
            if (cd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                var itemsCount = lstControl.Items.Count;
                var colorName = cd.Color;
                //Create rectangle object
                System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle myRect = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
                myRect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(colorName.A, colorName.R, colorName.G, colorName.B));

                myRect.Height = 10;
                myRect.Width = 50;

                TextBlock label = new TextBlock();
                label.Height = 10;
                label.Width = 50;

                Grid layout = new Grid();
                layout.Children.Add(myRect);
                layout.Children.Add(label);
                label.Text = colorName.Name;
                var newItem = new ListBoxItem
                {
                    Content = layout
                };

                lstControl.Items.Add(newItem);
            }
        }
```

Up to you, which method you are going to implement, but I would recommend you to select the first method(Binding).

Comment: @DavidJacoby let me know whether it worked for you or not